# Compare Data before storing in New Database from Last Value, Last 15 Min Value, and Previous Day Value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access

Friends,

Currently i m doing following....

i have a oss database from where i am fetching cpu usage value in 5 min interval and storing this value in my local ms access database. in ms access database im storing date, time, cpu usage,unit name in a table called "tblCdata".

im doing this by some application which i written in Visual basic 2010.

Q.i want to compare the cpu usage with the Last Value, Last 15 min value and Last Day value and generate an Alarm(that i will show in my VB application.) when it cross some threshold which is 50%??

plz guide me how to do it....

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
DateAdd("s", -15 * 60, Now())
```

to look up the record with max of logging time smaller than this.

Likewise

```
DateAdd("n", -24 * 60, Now())
```

for the day old log.

Or, if you create the variables in VB.NET, respectively:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15))
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
```

Comment: Q.i want to compare the cpu usage with the Last Value, Last 15 min value and Last Day value in LOCAL MS ACCESS DATABASE just before storing and generate an Alarm(that i will show in my VB application.) when it cross some threshold which is 50%??

Comment: Yes, look up the record matching the criteria, then check the logged value and raise the alarm if conditions are met.

Comment: Date Time Unit Cpu Usage
1/8/2015 0:05 101 45
1/8/2015 0:05 102 42
1/8/2015 0:10 101 44
1/8/2015 0:10 102 38
1/8/2015 0:15 101 41
1/8/2015 0:15 102 37
1/8/2015 0:20 101 49
1/8/2015 0:20 102 42
1/9/2015 0:05 101 38
1/9/2015 0:05 102 44
1/9/2015 0:10 101 39
1/9/2015 0:10 102 46
1/9/2015 0:15 101 35
1/9/2015 0:15 102 33
1/9/2015 0:20 101 50
Table is look like this in MS ACESS DATABASE
in this CPU usage value is storing in ms access like at 0:05,0:10 in five min interval ...i just want to compare the current value eg. 0:10 value with 0:05 value and also same thing for previous day value.

Comment: > compare the current value eg. 0:10 value with 0:05 value ... I don't follow. You wrote 15 minutes. As you are able to write the loggings, use similar method to read the logged values. You can't expect neither me or anyone else to write a complete code module for you.

Comment: That's an option if you use Access. But you are using VS2010.

Comment: That's a bit harsh. I can't guess what you are doing if that's what you mean. You haven't revealed neither your code, nor your table structure.

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?790307-Compare-Data-before-storing-in-New-Database-from-Last-Value-Last15-Min-value-lastDay